How do coredata and cloudkit communicate
I accidentally deleted some entities from Core Data on my macOS app. I had a backup of the sqlite file so I restored it. Now after some days the data disappeared again. My question is: if I restored the backup of Core Data but the data was deleted from CloudKit, what happens? Does the restored data get reuploaded on CloudKit or does it get deleted again?

My guess is that since you use an old backup iCloud will see that it has changes that are newer than the data on your device and then updates the local storage on the device with those changes. This reasoning is more based on how syncing should work than specific CloudKit knowledge

Did you delete entities or objects?

I deleted objects!
